# Split Rows and add Delimiter to text file using python

Tags: python, regex, data-cleaning

I am working to clean up a messy .txt file (text ID and raw text) for NLP analyses.

Currently it looks like:

```
@@0001 words 83 words, 90, words, 8989! @@0002 words, 98 words; words. @@0003 words 30 words ....
```

I would like to get it into a clean .txt or .csv format with each text on its own line and the ID separated from the text by a delimiter.

```
ID   | text 
0001 | words 83 words, 90, words, 8989!
0002 | words, 98 words; words. 
0003 | words 30 words ....
```

The following code creates a .txt file where each text is on its own line:

```
with open('/file_directory/file.txt', 'r') as file, open('/file_directory/file_cleaned.txt', 'w') as file2:
    for line in file:
        for word in line.split('@@'):
           file2.write(word + '\n')
```

e.g.,

```
0001 words 83 words, 90, words, 8989!
0002 words, 98 words; words. 
0003 words 30 words ....
```

However, I can't figure out how to add the delimiter since I can't match for either a specific series of integers or an integer length (e.g., 4+ digits). Currently, I am trying to first add the delimiters through a regular expression and then split lines, but I am running into regex and file writing issues.

```
import re
with open('/filedirectory/file.txt', 'r') as file, open('/filedirectory/file_cleaned.txt', 'w') as file2:
    text = file1.readlines()
    for line in text:
        text.re.split('^@\d{4,7}')
        for word in line.split('@@'):
           file2.write(word + '\n')
```

I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 're'
```

Any thoughts would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, it goes without saying that a `list` object has no attribute `re`.

You can use

```py
with open('/file_directory/file.txt', 'r') as file, open('/file_directory/file_cleaned.txt', 'w') as file2:
    file2.write(re.sub(r'@@\d+', r'\n\g<0> | ', file.read()).lstrip())
```

The regex matches `@@` and one or more digits, and replaces the matches with a line feed char, the whole match value, and a `|` char enclosed with single spaces.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/XIjw9X):

```py
import re
s = "@@0001 words 83 words, 90, words, 8989! @@0002 words, 98 words; words. @@0003 words 30 words ...."
print( re.sub(r'(@@\d+)', r'\n\1 | ', s).lstrip() )
```

Output:

```
@@0001 |  words 83 words, 90, words, 8989! 
@@0002 |  words, 98 words; words. 
@@0003 |  words 30 words ....
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex and Strings are two different types. As a reference, here is a list of every method for the [Python String Type](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_ref_string.asp) and for the [regex type objects](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp)

The reason you get an error is because you are trying to access a regex method from an object of type list*.

For your purposes, though:

1. String can be split using regex syntax,
2. Alternatively, you can use the `re` module to split them.

However, what you are trying to do is combine both.

You can either do:

```py
splitlines =  line.split('^@\d{4,7}')
```

Or, you can use regex:

```py
import re
splitlines = re.compile('^@\d{4,7}').split(line)
```